# How can I rename my project properly in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

While renaming my project using [Appendix: Utilities](https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts-v2/appendix/appendix-utilities/appendix-utilities.html) in Android studio, I'm having an error message on installing and running app on my android device. It shows me this
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t51T2.png).
Tell me how can I resolve this problem.

Comment: check applicationId in android `build.gradle` file

Comment: No issues their.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `AndroidManifest.xml` file and make sure the package in there is correct package.

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml file has correct package name and properties.

Comment: @AshutoshSharma can you delete the previous app and then install the new one?

Answer (score 0):

After doing all the stuff from **Appendix:utility**, go to **file>Invalidate cache/restart**. This works for me and hope this may work for you too.